# Как превратить в BeautifulSoup сохраненный HTML файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, файлы, beautiful-soup

Появилась необходимость поработать через `BeautifulSoup4` с сохраненной локально страницей из интернета. Проблема в том, что почему то не получается передать содержимое файла в `bs4` - первый `print` (для супа из файла) выдает 'None', хотя второй корректен.

Код такой:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open ('mdk.html','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    html = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

r = requests.get('https://mdk-arbat.ru/info/12').content
alter = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')

print(html.find('address'))
print(alter.find('address'))
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элемент DOM-а с контактами можно найти через `.find('ul', class_='tg-contactinfo')`, а строки через `.find_all('li')` и потом обойти их в цикле:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://mdk-arbat.ru/info/12')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
contact_info = soup.find('ul', class_='tg-contactinfo')
contact_rows = contact_info.find_all('li')

for row in contact_rows:
    print(row.text.strip())
```

выводит:

```
119019,Москва,
ул. Новый Арбат, 8
+7 (495) 789-35-91 сеть магазинов
+7 (495) 648-17-68 интернет-магазин
internet.magazin@mdk-arbat.ru
```

Попробуйте со своим `html` из файла делать то же самое?...

Comment: Что-то не разберусь с особенностями stackoverflow'а, и, вероятно, мой предыдущий комментарий не был опубликован. Проблем со спарсенным через requests html-код нет, и вся необходимая информация находится через bs4 как надо. Не получается все это провернуть с сохраненным файлом.

Comment: @ZorigtoBadmaev покажите 'mdk.html'?

Comment: [ссылка] (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/WbMV/85Q69Bupu). Вроде ничего особенного, просто через правую клавишу мыши сохранил исходный код страницы

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит обратиться к `class="tg-contactinfo"`
У меня всё работает `s = soup.find(class_='tg-contactinfo').find('address')`

Comment: Простите за неправильно сформулированный вопрос - перепутал значения, которые выдают print'ы - все поправил. Обращение к bs4 из файла через **class="tg-contactinfo"** у меня никаких результатов не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы нашлось - я сохранял исходный код страницы, а надо было саму страницу сохранять и уже ее превращать в Суп. Тогда все работает как надо. Всем спасибо!